# Unable to catch RuntimeError in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a python 2.7 plotting script using matplotlib and I want it to display what it just plotted, unless I run it from a non-X session on the institute server for batch-plotting. For such cases I simply tell it not to display anything.

However I don't want it to just stop if I forget doing that, which is why I'm trying to catch the RuntimeError exception like so:

```
try:
    pyplot.show()
except RuntimeError:
    print 'Could not display figure. No X-session?'
except:
    print 'Unexpected error:'
    raise
```

Doing this, however, I still get what I'd get without trying to catch anything, namely the Traceback and:

```
RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable
```

It doesn't print the 'Unexpected error', so it doesn't run into the second except.

What am I missing? It might be something very simple because I'm rather new to this.

EDIT:

The exception seems to be thrown before I try to display the plot, so maybe it is a different problem altogether.

Comment: Don't try to catch the error, instead check the display variable yourself:
`if not "DISPLAY" in os.environ` [...]

Comment: That sounds better, will try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was somewhere else altogether. I simply hava to use a different backend for matplotlib if I'm running from a non-X session. Checking the DISPLAY-variable like cel suggested and calling

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

on non-X sessions before importing pyplot solves the problem.